# How to refresh a table in Django, without using Ajax/jQuery for that

Tags: django, sqlite, python-3.6, reload

I want to refresh a particular table of a HTML page in Django, but I don't want to use Ajax/jQuery for that. 
The data in table comes from database. In my case, Django application with SQLite database. The table need to be refreshed every 1hour. 
Is there any way I can achieve this?
If yes, then how?

Comment: use celery    ...!!!!

Comment: You mean you want the browser to reload the page after 60 minutes? Or on every full hour?

Comment: @DanielHepper I want to reload after 60minutes

Comment: @HemanthSP thanks, celery helped.

Comment: @Reema Parakh celery it very easy and very reliable

Comment: @HemantSP while using celery, can I schedule my period task automatically once the worker is started?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax/JQuery would be the best way to do this dynamically.

The other option is to actually refresh the page:

```
<script>
     function refresh() {
         window.location.reload(true);
     }

     setTimeout(refresh, 3600000); // 1000ms * 60sec * 60min
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Non-Javascript solution, you *could* use a Meta Refresh header. Place this line in your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
```

Note that this approach is not really recommended and [deprecated by the World Wide Web Consortium](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element). It still works, but browsers might drop support at some point in the future.